# How to poll Selenium Hub for the number of it's registered Nodes?

Tags: testing, selenium-grid

I searched for any answer in the Selenium Grid [Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) but couldnt find anything.
Could it somehow be possible to poll the Selenium Hub and take back the number of nodes that are registered to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Grid Console (http://selenium.hub.ip.address:4444/grid/console) you will find valuable information about Grid's nodes, browsers, IPs, etc.

This is my grid. I have two nodes, one Linux and one Windows:

[image: Selenium Grid Console]

If you go through the links (Configuration, View Config,...) you will find information about each node and browser.

Answer (score 0):

I finally put together [this](http://w3h4ppyf3w.tumblr.com/page/6)

```
def grid_nodes_num(grid_console_url="http://my_super_company.com:8080/grid/console#"):
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(grid_console_url)
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
# print soup.prettify() # for debuggimg
grid_nodes = soup.find_all("p", class_="proxyid")
if grid_nodes == []:
print "-No Nodes detected. Grid is down!-"
else:
nodes_num = len(grid_nodes)
print "-Detected ",nodes_num," node(s)-"
return nodes_num
```